# How to sync an already converted video to ipod touch 4.1

Tags: ipod

How to synchronize an already converted video for the ipod touch to an ipod touch that hasn't been jailbroken?
I have an unjailbroken ipod and i want to put videos to it.
I have no problem adding music files to it. The version is 4.1 and Ubuntu is 10.04.1
Also, i want to know how to add games to it without using wifi but using Ubuntu.

Comment: @user8477: Could you remove the "Also how...add games..." part and ask it as a separate question?

Comment: You did not answer my main question which was about the videos to the ipod  -_

Answer (score 1):

The [official guide on how to transfer video](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iPodVideoTransferring) is pretty out of date, but refers to you either use gtkPod, or ThinLiquidFilm.

The [Ubuntu Updates site](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/194740) notes that if you use gtkPod, you must install libmp4v2-0 to enable aac support.

You can also try the new default music player, Banshee.  It supposedly supports [video syncing to iDevices](http://banshee.fm/features/) out of the box.

Finally, some users have reported success by installing this ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice1
```

Comment: So... I guess video synchronizing support for the ipod touch is still not available in Ubuntu :(  I already had libimobiledevice1 and the newest gtkpod installed which is v2.0.0.5dd6364 before posting this question.

Comment: Many people have reported it working, but it depends on your IOS version and whether the device is jailbroken.  In your case, it looks like you're out of luck until the gtkPod guys manage to reverse engineer whatever obfuscation Apple introduced this time around.  Their attitude is one of many reasons I won't touch Apple products, but many out there think differently and so you might get an updated package one day.

Comment: Also, you should add as much detail to your question as possible.  What have you already tried, what version are you running (Ubuntu, IOS), what packages have you installed, what guides have you followed.  Saves people wasting their time offering suggestions that you've already ruled out.

Comment: ok so I installed the latest stable libimobiledevice1,latest gtkpod, latest banshee. and ipod is 4.1 and unjailbroken (AGAIN) gktpod sees the songs and play them from the ipod like banshee but as for videos it may look like it's syncing but when i check the ipod it doesn't have any.                                                            Since video synchronizing problem is not resolved i'm guessing adding games to itouch using ubuntu but not wifi is out of the question?

Comment: Also, why did they say ipod touch support was out of the box when ubuntu  could only do 1 of the many other things the ipod could do??

Comment: When they saiid it was working out of the box, it was likely true for many (if not all) elements of iPod function.  Apple chop and change their product often specifically to break that compatibility and ensure that their customers are using iTunes.

Comment: not true... Only music syncing worked and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wfa025b6cos&feature=related this might help you

Comment: This video does not explain how to add videos to the ipod touch sorry you were no help at all. As i said already I've figured out how to add songs to it.

Comment: Can someone read the question and help me please???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too but, I found a solution that I believe always works:

1. right click video
2. click get info
3. go to options
4. click on media kind click on music video and done

Comment: can you be more specific to what program ur using cuz when i right click i on video i get open with movie player
open with
cut 
copy
make link etc.. so i don't know what ur saying or pointing at